# Два квадратных view

Tags: android, java, разметка

Добрый день. Нужно сделать что бы два ImageView делили экран по ширине пополам и имели квадратную форму (сторона квадрата равна половине ширины). С первой частью я справился описав вот такую разметку:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:weightSum="100">

 <ImageView 
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_weight="50"
         android:background="#0F0"/>

 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="#FF0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Теперь самое интересное, как сделать так что бы высота стала равна ширине?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот нашел ответ. Нужно переопределить метод onMeasure в классе унаследованном от imageView и подключить его в разметку. Причем достаточно сделать один такой класс, красота.
Вот пример 
https://github.com/chiuki/android-square-view/tree/master/src/com/sqisland/android/square_view